# What is the purpose of the $VERSION_INFO_SUFFIX in an Xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

Its used by agvtool - but Apple's documentation is seriously lacking here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/agvtool.8.html

Is this suffix added? Is it removed? Why would you do this?

Does anyone actually use this or know of a concrete use case?

Answer (score 1):

Although this could be used for anything, one use case for the `$VERSION_INFO_SUFFIX` ("Version Name Suffix" as it appears in Xcode) is to differentiate between several versions of the app on the same device, and enable a single device to install different binaries of the same application without changing the major/minor/bugfix version or build number.  This suffix is added to the version number at buildtime.  But to be honest I've never seen this used in practice, or in Apple's [guides on versioning](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1827/_index.html).

Comment: thanks - yeah thats about the same I came up with too… So you you think this could be used to do something like append a "b" to the build number like 3.2 (235b)?

Comment: @CoreyFloyd theoretically yes.  I tried updating this value in an iOS application and printing the version number values from the plist, but didn't see my suffix appended at the end.  It's possible this is only used by avgtool as a check to see if the version number or other plist values need to be incremented.  Or it's just not supported at all.